# All my xml is empty in design

Tags: android-layout

All my android studio xml is empty in design. Any ideas? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZZC8.png)

Comment: What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpuH1Z8Rzfg

I changed my build file in android. I had alpha3 before.

dependencies {

.....

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

.......

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
.....

}